# Настройка ZTE W300

Tags: zte, сеть

Здравствуйте.

Есть железка ZTE W300 и желание настроить ее по следующим параметрам:

Eth1 - со статическим IP(маской/шлюзом/DNS серверами).

Eth2/3/4 + Wlan - настроить DHCP сервер(с заданным диапазоном и куртизанками).

Идея заключается в создании моста, вроде как, между двумя сетями. Первая - линия от провайдера, при этом вторая сеть - локальная, подключение к провайдеру через VPN.

P.S. Буду признателен за любую информация о возможном способе реализации такой конфигурации.

Comment: Какие еще куртизанки и мосты и vpn. Вам всего лишь нужна маршрутизация между Eth1 и всем остальным, верно ? Что б локальные женщины могли в контактик ходить?

Comment: Да, хочу заменить windows server 2003(DHCP), т.к. установлен на старой сбойной железке, на данный роутер(если возможно). Есть ли вариант сделать через веб-интерфейс или лучше искать инструкции CLI?

Comment: Я думаю ваша задача и через веб решается. CLI, который по заявлению разработчиков cisco like, нифига не  cisco like,вообщем не советую.